# Acceleration as a function of position and time

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, acceleration, velocity, calculus

I know if you have an acceleration as a function of $t$, $a(t)$, to find the velocity you simply integrate $a(t)$ with respect to $t$. Moreover, if the acceleration was a function of position, $a(x)$, you use the fact that $a(x) = v(x) \cdot dv/dx$ and solve for $v(x)$. However, what if the function of acceleration was dependent on both $x$ and $t$, $a(x,t)$. How would you solve for a velocity $v(x,t)$ ?

Comment: Can you elaborate what this would mean? Is this different from, say $a(x(t))$, which is what it seems like the beginning of the question is actually about?

Comment: The first example is purely dependent on time. Say you are looking at an oscillator where $a(t) = cos(t) $ for example. The last example is multi variable, for example, the acceleration of the same oscillator might exponentially decrease over a distance $x$ so $a(x,t) = e^{-x} cos(t)$.

Comment: Are you familiar with differential equations?

Comment: Yes. I am familiar.

Comment: So then there you go.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your point. If $a(x,t) = f(x,t)$ how would i form an equation to solve for $v(x,t)$ ?

Answer (score 2):

This is a standard mechanics problem.

There definition of acceleration is
$$a=\frac{\text d^2x}{\text dt^2}$$

So if you know what $a(x,t)$ is, and you have initial conditions like $x(t_0)=x_0$ and $v(t_0)=v_0$, then you just need to solve the differential equation $$\frac{\text d^2x}{\text dt^2}=a(x,t)$$

From there it is straightforward to determine the velocity.

Comment: Ah, that's clear now, thank you!

Comment: @TimCP Please up vote all useful answers, and make sure to accept the answer that sufficiently answers your question.

Comment: What does $a(x,t)$ mean tho for a single particle? Acceleration is defined along a trajectory so ultimately, $a(x,t)$ should be treated as $a(x(t),t)$ or, essentially, just $a(t)$. For example, if $a$ is constant, we'd have $x\sim t^2$ and so I can formally write something like $a \sim x/t^2$, but it's more or less meaningless. In particular, it doesn't mean $a$ is $a(x,t)$, because one cannot independently vary $x$ and $t$.

Comment: @DvijD.C. I was thinking of it more in terms of just a force divided by mass. As in a particle can experience a force that has both spatial and temporal dependence. I asked the OP about $a(x(t))$ in a comment in the main post. I don't think that is what they mean to ask about here.

Comment: Ok, I see. I mean there are subtleties with treating it like that which I'm not sure OP is aware. In particular, the variable $X$ which is the particle's position would not be the same variable as the $x$ in $a(x,t)$ if we are treating $x$ as a label to label the force field at each point in space. In particular, $d^2X(t)/dt^2= a(x=X(t), t)$ is how the equation would explicitly read where $X$ is the position of the particle and $x$ is the label on the force field.

Comment: Okay, so i posed this question because i have a set up where i have a magnetic field from a solenoid that changes in time and space. I introduce a ball bearing to the field and would like to know how the velocity of the ball varies. Now because the field varies in space and time, this means the force on the ball will too. Sorry for the confusions, i'm very new to this.

Answer (score 0):

the acceleration a is:

$$a(t)=\frac{dv(t)}{dt}$$

thus:

$$v(t)=\int a(t)\,dt+v_0\tag 1$$

if $a(t)\mapsto a(x(t),t)$

you get from equation (1)

$$v(t)=\int a(x(t),t)\,dt+v_0$$

and $x(t)$ is the solution of the differential equation $\ddot{x}=a(x(t),t)$